# Give an example of a field extension $K/F$ with $[K:F]=3$ but $K \neq F(\sqrt[3] b)$ for any $b \in F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Give an example of a field extension $K/F$ with $[K:F]=3$ but $K \neq F(\sqrt[3] b)$ for any $b \in F$.

My attempt was consider $\Bbb F_3$ and the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x+1$ here $p(x)$ has no root in $\Bbb F_3$ hence irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$.

Consider $K=\Bbb F_3[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$. It is a field extension of deg $3$ over $\Bbb F_3$ but I think $K \neq \Bbb F_3(\sqrt[3] b)$ for any $b \in \Bbb F_3$. (why??)

Comment: Here $\sqrt[3]b$ is nothing but a notation of an element in $a\in \Bbb F_3$ s.t $a^3=b$.

Comment: Sorry $a$ might not be in $\Bbb F_3$. Right?

Comment: Hmm so what will be the approach after my try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29725/discussion-between-user152715-and-git-gud).

Comment: If $b\in\Bbb{F}_3$, then $b^3=b$ (check this by hand if you didn't know it - a similar thing holds for all finite fields). Therefore
$$x^3-b=x^3-b^3=(x-b)^3.$$ Your claim follows from this.

Comment: In other words, in $\Bbb F_3$, everything is its own cube root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the minimal polynomial of the algebraic number $\alpha=2\cos\left({2\pi\over 7}\right)=\zeta_7+\zeta_7^{-1}$ over $\Bbb Q$, $x^3+x^2-2x-1$, which generates a totally real extension of degree $3$. Since it is the splitting field for a cubic, it contains all the roots of the polynomial. But since it is totally real, it cannot be of the form $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{b})$, since the latter has only one real embedding and our field has three. Hence $\Bbb Q\left(2\cos\left({2\pi\over 7}\right)\right)/\Bbb Q$ is such an extension.

Comment: Then we have to prove the polynomial is irreducible and proving it, will be little bit more complicated.

Comment: What about my try?

Comment: @user152715 you don't actually have to do that directly, you know that it is the fixed subfield (fixed by complex conjugation) of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$, hence automatically has degree $3$ by the FTGT.

Comment: @user152715 your attempt also works:  you can tell because all elements of $\Bbb F_3$ are cubes, hence any proper extension must be adjoining something else, because $\Bbb F_3(\sqrt[3] b)=\Bbb F_3$ when $b\in\Bbb F_3$. In particular there is only one cube root of $b$ in all fields of characteristic $3$ since $x^3-b$ is purely inseparable in this characteristic.

Comment: But $\sqrt[3]b$ might not be in $\Bbb F_3$ so how do I argue after that?

Comment: How do we prove that it is purely inseparable?

Comment: @user152715 Just factor it, $x^3-b= (x-b)^3$. Unique factorization said that $b$ is the only root.

Comment: @user152715 is there anything else that can be said to help your understanding? You stopped clarifying, but haven't accepted anything, so it seems in limbo, still.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. No I am satisfied with your clarification and the answer as well.

Comment: @AdamHughes Sorry to bother you, but I’m confused about your statement “the latter has only one real embedding and our field has three”. I wonder what are these “embeddings”. Apologize advance if it’s too obvious for you. Thanks!

Comment: @FengShao They are given by $x\mapsto\alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of the polynomial.

Comment: @AdamHughes Aha that’s right, thank you very much.